# Identification sci-fi book (series) -- Humans as servants & Alien masters with superior memories

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

More than 10 years ago, while traveling, I read one book in a series. I found it in a book exchange.

I think it was about humans in the far future being servants or slaves of an alien race.

The one characteristic of the this alien race is that they remember everything. They hear a story or view something and it is ingrained in their memory, there to stay for the rest of their life and can retrieve every detail at will. Since humans don't have that they are seen as inferior. I think also swords or other sharp weapons played a role.

I remember enjoying it tremendously and wanted to reread it and read the rest of the series, but unfortunately I never found it again.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/author/show/989968.C_J_Cherryh?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Faded_Sun_Trilogy?

Comment: Well, I'll be damned. That might be it. These mri have infallible memories?

Comment: If its' not the above, it might be Donald Moffet's 'The genesis quest' and 'second genesis' (1986) in which future humanity, recreated from broadcast genetic data sent from earth is subservient (second class citizens) to the Nar, a race that regard humanity as immature and illogical and forgetful.

Comment: @DerrickdeRuiter: No, the regul, for whom the mri fight as mercenaries, are the ones with a perfect memory. If The Faded Sun Trilogy is the book you are looking for, you are misremembering quite a bit: Humans are neither servants nor slaves of the Regul, but their enemies. But the mri are depicted as very human-like, so maybe you mixed that up. And yes, the mri use and even prefer sharp melee weapons to guns and the like, so sharp weapons play an important role.

Comment: @straycat, haha, well. it is 10 years ago, so I am already very happy you guys were able to help me out!

Comment: Thanks, everyone. Indeed it was the Faded Sun Trilogy. Located it online and currently reading!

Answer (score 2):

This could possibly be the *Lilith's Brood* trilogy (*Dawn*, *Adulthood Rites*, and *Imago*) by Octavia E. Butler.

[image: Lilith's Brood Collection]

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilith%27s_Brood):

> ...story begins after a terrible nuclear war that left the earth
>   uninhabitable. Humans are all but extinct. The few survivors are
>   plucked from the dying earth by an alien race, the Oankali. The
>   protagonist Lilith Iyapo (a black human female) awakens 250 years
>   after the war on a living Oankali ship. At first, she is repulsed by
>   the alienness of her saviors/captors.

While the humans are not slaves, they are initially only brought out of suspension into contexts where they are either kept in solitude and interrogated, or where they are integrated into an Oankali family unit.

The Oankali do remember everything, even as far back as being in utero, and this is one of the improvements they extend to humans who become family with them - in the first book, the Ooloi who is attempting to bring Lilith into a familial unit refuses to allow her paper because it is a crutch.  She asks for it to try and learn their language; he is contemptuous that if she would permit (via genetic manipulation) her memory to be extended she would not need paper to learn the language, she would merely start remembering everything.

Lilith later would go on to shepherd several dozen other humans through awakening and into awareness of their status as guests of an alien species.  Humans being humans, they end up using edged weapons on each other and on the Oankali.  In the second and third books, as humans and Oankali resettle on parts of the healing earth, the non-integrated humans bootstrap themselves up to guns, which are more commonly used on other humans than on Oankali.

Comment: Awesome, guys! I guess it is the Faded Sun trilogy, but other ones sound interesting as well!